# facebook detects browser automation when selenium running headless

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, webdriver, chatbot

When running this selenium script for fb chatbot in **windowed chrome runs fine**. **In headless mode it is detected and blocked** even with python virtual display.

I want to **run the script in headless mode with pyvirtualdisplay while avoiding detection** so that I may execute remotely as a daily scheduled task.

This is for an **ubuntu 18.04 droplet on digital ocean**.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
display.start()
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
chrome_options.add_argument("--load-extension=" + me.favoriteExtension)
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
})
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

def login(submitBtn):
    email = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
    btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath(submitBtn)
    email.send_keys(me.fbUser)
    password.send_keys(me.fbPassword)
    btn.click()

def respondToNewMessages():
    browser.get("http://facebook.com/messages/t/")
    print('responding to new msgs')
    conversations = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('*//ul[@aria-label="Conversation List"]/li')
    print('found '+str(len(conversations)) + ' conversations')
    index = 0
    for conversation in conversations:
        index += 1
        firstMsg = conversation.find_element_by_xpath('./div/a/div/div//span/span')
        print('Found first message ' + firstMsg.text + ' conversation #' + str(index))
        msgFontSize = firstMsg.value_of_css_property('font-weight')
        if(not int(msgFontSize) > 400):
            print('conversation #' + str(index) + ' is an old convo')
        else:
            firstMsg = conversation.find_element_by_xpath('./div/a/div/div//span/span')
            firstMsg.click()
            with open('awaymsg.txt') as f:
                for line in f: 
                    ActionChains(browser).send_keys(line).perform() 
                    ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
            f.close()
    return True

browser.get("http://facebook.com") # load the web page
login("//*[@id='u_0_b' and not(@type='hidden')]|//button[@id='loginbutton' and @type='submit' and @name='login' and not(@type='hidden')]") # Attempt login

while ( 'login' in browser.current_url): # if login fails try again and / or dismiss checkpoint
    login("//*[@id='u_0_b' and not(@type='hidden')]|//button[@id='loginbutton' and @type='submit' and @name='login' and not(@type='hidden')]")
    if 'checkpoint' in browser.current_url:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value='Yes']").click()
    browser.get("http://facebook.com/messages/t/") # exit when messages are loaded

browser.implicitly_wait(5) 
conversations = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('*//ul[@aria-label="Conversation List"]/li')  # count conversations

respondToNewMessages()

browser.close()
```

Expected - headless w virtual display would reflect running in windowed chrome.

Actual - windowed runs fine, headless is detected and blocked by Facebook.

Comment: So, what's your question? How to circumvent Facebook's security measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyvirtualdisplay` and browser's headless mode are made to do the same, so if you use `pyvirtualdisplay` then you shouldn't set `chrome_options.add_argument('headless')`.

Install xvfb (`sudo apt-get install xvfb`) and set it as backend with:

```
display = Display(backend="xvfb", visible=0, size=(800, 800))
```